# Project Euler - How is this haskell code so fast?

Tags: python, haskell, python-3.x

I'm working on problem 401 in project euler, I coded up my solution in python but it's going to take a few days to run, obviously I'll need to speed it up or use a different approach. I came across a solution in Haskell that looks almost identical to my python solution but completes almost instantaneously.

Can someone explain how it is so fast? (**I AM NOT ASKING FOR HELP OR SOLUTIONS TO PROBLEM 401**)

```
divisors n = filter (\x -> n `mod` x == 0) [1..(n`div`2)] ++ [n]
sigma2 n = sum $ map (\x -> x * x) (divisors n)
sigma2big n = sum $ map (sigma2)[1..n]
let s2b = sigma2big 10^15
putStrLn ("SIGMA2(10^15) mod 10^9 is " ++ (show (mod s2b 10^9)))
```

From my understanding it is just using trial division to generate a list of divisors, squaring and summing them, and then summing the results from 1 to n.

EDIT: forgot my python code

```
from time import clock


def timer(function):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = clock()
        print(function(*args, **kwargs))
        runtime = clock() - start
        print("Runtime: %f seconds." % runtime)

    return wrapper


@timer
def find_answer():
    return big_sigma2(10**15) % 10**9

def get_divisors(n):
    divs = set()
    for i in range(1, int(sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            divs.add(i)
            divs.add(n // i)
    return divs

def sigma2(n):
    return sum(map(lambda x: x**2, get_divisors(n)))

def big_sigma2(n):
    total = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        total += sigma2(i)
    return total

if __name__ == "__main__":
    find_answer()
```

Comment: It'd certainly help if you showed us your python code as well.

Comment: The real question might be: Why is your Python code so slow.

Comment: I don't know Haskell, but my two guesses for why your code is so much slower is that your code builds explicit lists and sets where the Haskell code is lazy, and the Haskell is compiled to native code where the Python is bytecode interpreted. In particular, if this is Python 2, `range(1, 10**15+1)` is going to eat all your memory.

Comment: BTW very inefficient solution. you're practically bruteforcing. 10^22 operations roughly

Comment: Oddly enough this Haskell code isn't particularly efficient. Indeed there are several parts where we are unnecessarily costly, appending `[n]` instead of the constant time `n :` operation for example.. And this is still very very fast in GHCi..

Comment: The funny thing is, when this finishes after a few days, you won't know whether it was actually correct, because it just ignores the result…

Comment: Anyway, assuming this is Python 2, change it to use iterators and other lazy objects whenever possible (`xrange` instead of `range`, `itertools.imap` instead of `imap`). Also, maybe run it in PyPy instead of CPython. If it's still more than 50x slower than the Haskell code, you have a problem.

Comment: @user2357112 its Python 3 so xrange is not needed. I know python isn't very fast but the runtimes I'm getting are many orders of magnitude different. The python code is projected to complete in a few days where the haskell code instantly gives me an answer.

Comment: `for i in range(1, 10**15+1)` is a lot of iterations. That's going to take quite some time.

Comment: @abarnert Yea I left out the part where I used a decorated to wrap the code in a timer, without that it would indeed not show the result.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
Prelude> sigma2big 1000
401382971
(0.48 secs, 28491864 bytes)

Prelude> sigma2big 10^3
103161709
(0.02 secs, 1035252 bytes)

Prelude> (sigma2big 10)^3
103161709
```

function precedence (shh...)

Comment: Oh my god I can't believe I didn't notice that...
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using `Integer` for your calculations and not `Int` since `10^15` will overflow an `Int` value.

If you change:

```
let s2b = sigma2big 10^15
```

to:

```
let s2b = sigma2big (10^15 :: Integer)
```

the Haskell code runs out of memory in `ghci` and I didn't bother to wait for it to complete when running the compiled version.

Comment: The haskell code is not mine, I wrote the python code. I'm wondering why the haskell code is so much faster than mine.

Comment: This is incorrect.  As noted by the other answer it is the difference of `(sigma2big 10)^15 /= sigma2bit (10^15)` you are seeing.  The type defaulting of otherwise ambiguous Integrals is actually `Integer` by default.